# Switching between windows or tabs doesn't finish

Tags: google-chrome

When I switch between windows or tabs (Chrome, PHPStorm), the rendering of the page doesn't complete. It looks like the screenshot below and only changes when I resize the window or scroll down.

Playing video's is not a problem, so it's not just about slow rendering.

I've got no clue how to debug this problem. How can I find out what's the actual problem?

[image: Screen rendering doesn't complete]

Comment: Does the same occur for Firefox? You mention the code editor PHPStorm. Do you mean that when displaying the raw source files in the editor that they don't render, or when you display the output (i.e. HTML)?

If so, I would look into how HTML rendering is done on Ubuntu and whether there are any shared 'modules' between the programs that could have an underlying configuration issue/bug.

Comment: I also see this issue. Did you find a solution or report this as a bug? I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 with Chrome 45. It also occurs in Chromium. I've noticed that opening pdfs in another tab increases the likelihood of reproducing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514510). It looks like there is a feature called virtual contexts that is causing problems with Intel MESA drivers.

[This](https://codereview.chromium.org/1399653002/#ps1) is the code review for the respective regression.

**UPDATE (10/16/2015)**:

This fix is available in [Chrome Dev](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/10/dev-channel-update_15.html) (48.0.2535).

Comment: Thanks! It looks "Use System Titlebar and Borders" works for me as well (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514510#c7), but I'll try it a bit longer.

Comment: Interesting. Reading through some comments, that option didn't work so well for some users. By the way, the patch has been committed. However, I don't know when we will be able to download the version containing this fix.